# React build not loading all chunks

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**simple** problem that I've seen asked in a few places and seems to have no structured answer. Because of this I though I would start a thread here and maybe get something going that will help everybody!

Diving right into it, I have build a **react app** using `create-react-app`, compiling this into a **prod** version using `npm run build` it does everything that it needs to and completes successfully.

After all of this we can observe the compiled **app** having multiple **chunks**.

All good and well until we enter the **app** and try to navigate to a different page, where we find it is not loading any other chunks besides the chunks responsible for the **first page** you access when entering the **app**.

This is the base problem, I realize I'm not giving any snippets or anything but again, this is because the problem seems very general, there are a lot of people with different applications and code looking for a solution to this and haven't found something practical and normal (having messaged some on forums and such).

If anybody needs any specific information to may case please ask and I will happily provide :)

As far as I can tell, this is **webpack** related or something like that, **webpack** from what I understand only includes **one chunk** and then loads the others as needed, is this correct?

If so and if the **chunks** are created but not loaded when switching to other pages, then it seems like a **webpack** issue, but what?

When you, then other developers, create a **react app** and it contains multiple **chunks**, do they load well?

Any and all information is appreciated, lets try to tackle this issue!

P.S. If you go into the **compiled production build** and manually add all the chunks, everything works perfectly. I will try to add any and all information to this thread as I find out more.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) carefully?

Comment: The webpack config can help on the investigation, especially for the code splitting part. Please provide that.

Comment: Hello, I've tried reading the documentation you point out but everything seems old to me... I don't understand what I'm overlooking, what I do see every time I look for something though is people complaining about the lack of documentation :(

Comment: Here is my __webpack__ config https://codepen.io/Nick09/pen/GVjBxV. Please let me know if there's anything else I can read or link here to further this :) Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not figure it out back then, the only solution for the app to work that I've found was to add the chunks inside of the index file manually. Its not much and its not proper but that was the only answer back then.